# Counting number of elements in a combinatorial set

Tags: combinatorics

I don't know the exact nomenclatures (the title itself may be unclear or wrong), but I will do my best to be clear and to use what little established nomenclatures I know. I'm not a mathematician or anything close to that, so I would ask if any answer given could take that into account.

Let $S_n$ be a set of $2^n$ elements, where each of these elements is a n-tuple in the form

$(a, b, c, d, ... n)$ where $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, ..., $n$ can have a value of either $0$ or $1$.

So, in $S_4$, the number of elements would be $16$, and they would be

$$
(0, 0, 0, 0)\\
(0, 0, 0, 1)\\
(0, 0, 1, 0)\\
(0, 0, 1, 1)\\
(0, 1, 0, 0)\\
(0, 1, 0, 1)\\
(0, 1, 1, 0)\\
(0, 1, 1, 1)\\
(1, 0, 0, 0)\\
(1, 0, 0, 1)\\
(1, 0, 1, 0)\\
(1, 0, 1, 1)\\
(1, 1, 0, 0)\\
(1, 1, 0, 1)\\
(1, 1, 1, 0)\\
(1, 1, 1, 1)
$$

A pairing between two elements of $S_n$ is defined as any two n-tuples which differ by the value of only one of their elements. As an example, here are all the other tuples in $S_4$ that can be paired with the tuple $(0, 0, 0, 1)$:

$$
(0, 0, 0, 0)\\
(0, 0, 1, 1)\\
(0, 1, 0, 1)\\
(1, 0, 0, 1)
$$

Let $P$ be the set of all possible pairings between the elements of $S_n$, what is the number of elements of $P$?

I think this problem belongs in enumerative combinatorics, but I can't wrap my head around it and come up with a way to solve it. I suspect I will have to make a compound counting of some sort, probably something similar to the school problem when we take the number of boys in class and the number of girls and then we have to count how many different configurations of the students council formed by 4 boys and 3 girls we can have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are $2^n$ elements in $S^n$. Each of those $2^n$ elements can be connected to $n$ different elements in $S^n$: namely, you can change any one of the $n$ bits of the element. This gives a count of $n2^n$. But now note that you've counted every pairing twice: you've counted it once from each end of the pairing. So you need to divide this number by 2. The total number of pairings that can be made is $n2^{n-1}$.

Comment: I noticed the problem of counting pairings more than once, but I couldn't prove to myself that the number of time they repeated themselves was 2 for every pairing. Is it easy to demonstrate that part to me, if it isn't a bother? I *think* I got it, but I can't prove it to myself mathematically. This part is probably intuitive to you.

Comment: My problem with just dividing it by 2 is because of how my mind sees the issue. for example, (0, 0, 0, 0) can make a pairing with (0, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0) and (1, 0, 0, 0). So I'm tempted to think there's more to it. But if I think about it, (0, 0, 0, 0) appears in each of these pairings only once, and I have to divide by two only because the elements of the pair could be swapped (which does not make it a different pair). I think i got it.

Comment: You got it exactly right. Note that once you get to the dividing stage, you are thinking of *each pairing that you've counted*, no longer about *elements of $S_n$*. A pairing is for example $((0,1,1,0),(0,1,1,1))$ and it's clear that you've counted it twice: once "from the $(0,1,1,0)$ side" and once "from the $(0,1,1,1)$ side".